# factory not defined in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('part3', []);
app.controller('Part3Controller' ,function ($scope) {
    $scope.Message1 = "apek";
    $scope.IsLogedIn = false;
    $scope.Message = '';
    $scope.Submitted = false;
    $scope.IsFormValid = false;
    $scope.LoginData = {

        UserName: '',
        Password: ''
    };
    $scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function (newVal) {
        $scope.IsFormValid = newVal;
    });

    $scope.Login = function () {

        $scope.Submitted = true;

        if ($scope.IsFormValid) {
            alert("eeeeee")
            alert("dsds")
            serv.GetUser($scope.LoginData).then(function (d) {
                alert("dsdsdfsdfs");
                if (d.data.UserName != null) {
                    alert("he;llo1");
                    $scope.IsLoggedIn = true;
                    $scope.Message = "Successfully Login" + d.data.FullName;
                }
                else {

                    alert("Invalid Credential")
                }
            })
        }
    }



})

app.factory('serv', function ($http) {
    alert("helloo");
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetUser = function (d) {
        $scope.Submitted = true;
        return $http({

            url: '/Data/UserLogin',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            header: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
    return fac;
});
```

I had written above code for login functionality in my app but it is not calling factory "serv" its showing error "angular.min.js:92 ReferenceError: serv is not defined"

"angular.min.js:92 ReferenceError: serv is not defined"

Answer (score 4):

When you want to use a factory or service with a controller in angular, you need to inject them with that. We have:
`app.factory('name_of_factory', factory_function);`
and controller:
`app.controller('name_of_controller', controller_function($scope,factory_name_you_want_to_use) { //blah blah });`
That was some of explanation, **you just need to inject name of factory with your controller. Your Controller JS will look like this**:

```
app.controller('Part3Controller' ,function ($scope,serv){//yourcode});
```

Answer (score 0):

need to inject `serv` factory to the controller

```
controller('Part3Controller' ,function ($scope,serv) {
```

Comment: still it is not executing " url: '/Data/UserLogin'," Userlogin function in DataController in mvc

Comment: .factory('LoginService', function ($http) {
    alert("helloo");
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetUser = function (d,e) {
        
        $scope.Submitted = true;
        return $http({
            url: '/Data/UserLogin',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            header: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
        alert(4)
    };
    return fac;
});

Comment: remove `$scope.Submitted = true;` in the factory. factory does not support scope variables